# how to clear search results when another search is action'd

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a search box that displays a list item, and clears the search field after the user clicks the button...but how can i remove the searched item if the user was going to search again ? So the page only displays the new search result and not previous

```
var noNameFound = true;
var searchedStudent = [];

// Stores names in an array where names can be pulled and shown when button is clicked
var studentArr = [];

$('.student-list').children().each(function(){
    studentArr.push(this);
});

// this will search through the array to locate the student.
$('.userSearch').on('click', function(){
    //stores users search into a variable
    var searchRequest = $('#search-input').val();

    //search through array here...
    for (var i = 0; i < studentArr.length; i++) {
        var studentstr = studentArr[i].innerText;

        if (studentstr.indexOf(searchRequest) !== -1) {

            console.log('YAY!! the name:: ' + searchRequest + ' ::is in our list');
            $(".student-list li").css("display","none"); // removes all students from the list.

            searchedStudent.push(studentArr[i]);
            $(searchedStudent).show(); // displayes the searched student.

            noNameFound = false;
        }
    }

    // removes stundent-item if no user can be found, and asks user to click buttont to refresh page.
    if (noNameFound) {
        var errorMessage = $('<p class="errMessage">Sorry but we were unable to locate the name you were looking for, <br> please click <button class="refresh">here</button> to refresh the page and try again.</p>');
        $(".student-list").prepend(errorMessage);
        $('.student-item').css('display', 'none');
        $('.refresh').on('click', function(){
            location.reload();
        });
    }

    if(noNameFound){
        //stops users searching an empty search field.
        $('.userSearch').prop('disabled',true);

        $('#search-input').keyup(function(){
            $('.userSearch').prop('disabled', this.value === ""? true : false);
        });
    }

});
```

This is what i have so far

Comment: I'd need more code to see but my guess it's that you won't delete array after click, try add after $('.userSearch').on('click', function() ... searchedStudent = [];

Comment: heres my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qvk8rzpm/

Comment: you need to add html code to that also

Comment: sorry just updated: https://jsfiddle.net/1gdqreoe/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset `searchedStudent` array before `for` loop in click event handler.

```
// rest of the code

// this will search through the array to locate the student.
$('.userSearch').on('click', function(){
    //stores users search into a variable
    var searchRequest = $('#search-input').val();

    searchedStudent = []; // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<< HERE

    //search through array here...
    for (var i = 0; i < studentArr.length; i++) {
        var studentstr = studentArr[i].innerText;

// rest of the code
```

Actually you can remove the `searchedStudent` array altogether and still achieve the functionality.. give it a try.

Comment: well that was friggin' easy, i just had to declare the array within the function. Can i ask why? Just so i understand. But thanks for helping me out with this one matey...much love